# How to play video before launching the app

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to run an intro for a game I'm developing using Kivy. Luckily, Kivy offers VideoPlayer class for playing videos which I find very nice.

I managed to play the video by returning the object like this:

```
class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        game = Game()
        Window.size = game.size
        videoplayer = VideoPlayer(source='assets/intro.mp4', state='play',
                       options={'allow_stretch': True})
        return videoplayer
```

Which as you may have guessed plays the video but it won't run the app afterwards because I'm not returning the app object. So I've tried this:

```
class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        game = Game()
        Window.size = game.size
        self.play_video()
        return game

    def play_video(self):
        return VideoPlayer(source='assets/intro.mp4', state='play',
                       options={'allow_stretch': True})
```

To my surprise that didn't work either. How can I get Kivy to play the intro and then launch the app ?

The docs https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.videoplayer.html?highlight=videoplayer#kivy.uix.videoplayer.VideoPlayer tells me how to return the VideoPlayer object to play it but says nothing about how to run anything after the video has finished.

Comment: You need to return the VideoPlayer, then bind a function to create the rest of your app's gui once the video finishes. Probably something like binding to the `state` property of the VideoPlayer would be ideal, assuming this changes when the video finishes.

Comment: @inclement  Can you give me an example of binding ?

Comment: @mr_incredible change to `self.video = self.play_video()`

Comment: @eyllanesc  That plays the audio from the video in the app. No video.

Comment: It's almost as if I can either return the game object or VideoPlayer object from the build method but can't one after another.

Comment: http://inclem.net/2019/12/18/kivy/kivy_tutorial_004_event_bindings/

Comment: Returning one thing after another from a method wouldn't make any sense. You need to change your mental model for how the gui works: whatever you want to see on the screen, you have to program by changing what widgets are displayed